# Difference between .NET Core SDK and TargetFramework versions

Tags: .net-core

I don't really understand what is the difference between the dotnet sdk version and the `TargetFramework` version specified in my `csproj` file.

For example, my current project is using `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` version, but `dotnet --version` command returns `2.2.100`. So the major version is the same, but  the minor differs by 1.

Is it backwards compatible and `netcoreapp2.1` apps can run on newer versions of dotnet sdk or something completely different?

`dotnet --info`:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   2.2.100
Commit:    b9f2fa0ca8

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.17134
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.0
  Commit:  1249f08fed

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Can you also show what `dotnet --info` says on your machine?

Comment: @omajid updated the question

Comment: @HansPassant, could you please elaborate on what is the difference between the two and how they are meant to work together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between SDK and Runtime in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733014/whats-the-difference-between-sdk-and-runtime-in-net-core)