# Unable to build C# / .NET Core project on Windows 11

Tags: c#, .net-core

If I create a new project (or open old working project) with the target framework .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5.0 or any newer versions using VS2019 or VS2022, and I try running or building the project, I get the following errors:

[Screenshot of the error (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGvHv.png)

[Screenshot of the error (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbAkr.png)

I tried to install everything, but The SDKs aren't found in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk" folder.

[Screenshot of what I installed (as an example VS20122)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hePsg.png)

[The result of dotnet --info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HciIj.png)

[Screenshot of the list of the "target framework" in the project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGktq.png)

[Screenshot of what I installed (as an example VS20122)2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSQPq.png)

[Screenshot of what I installed (as an example VS20122)3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwu3D.png)

PS : With .NET Framework I don't have that problem.

Comment: Run `dotnet --info`, does 5.0 show up in the SDK section? What is the `TargetFramework` value in your csproj file?

Comment: I see the runtimes in your installation, but not the SDKs. See: [Download .NET SDKs for Visual Studio](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks). Or use the VS installer. See also: [What's the difference between SDK and Runtime in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702098/880990).

Comment: @gunr2171  I edited the body of my question and included some other screenshots to respond your question.
in the csproj file :
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: 1) Please post text as _text_, not images. 2) You don't have 5.0 in the SDK section, so it makes sense you can't compile .Net 5 code. 3) Your project says it targets .Net 6, not 5. In all cases, please use Olivier's link above to install the right version of the .Net SDK that you need.

Comment: @gunr2171
1) I wanted to show you everything to get things clear. 2) & 3) I've installed All the .Net core listed in the VS Installer but the VS doesn't show them in the target framework and was weird. + 4) I Solved the issue by just installing the X86 of the .Net core (by default the VS Installer installed the X64 version of the runtimes and SDKs.) and that was weirder.